# Trying to install KISS IDE on Ubuntu, Qt5 and cmake problem

Tags: compiling, qt

The KISS IDE is an IDE used for programming, compiling, and exporting code/executables to a device called the KIPR link.

http://www.kipr.org/products/kiss-ide

https://github.com/kipr/kiss

It is meant for Windows and OS X, but you can compile the source in Linux. I have installed the requirements, but apparently did not install qt5 correctly. When I `cd ~/Documents/kiss-master/` and run `mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..` it throws this error:

```
Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Declarative" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Declarative_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Declarative" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

After using both `locate` and `find`, I could not find this file in my hard drive.

I have no idea what this means. This is my first encounter with Qt. Could someone please help and explain what I should do?

If you need anything concerning my file system setup, please ask in the comments and I will edit the question to include it. Same goes for any commands you need to see the output of.

Thanks!!!